# Wagtail ModelAdmin - multiselect filters

Tags: django, wagtail

is there a way to make filters in Wagtail modeladmin index page multiselectable? Especialy for fields that are Foreign to the model, but also to Simple lists created from values.

Best Regards,
Konrad